# How do I get my application.js (jQuery) file to execute a script from somewhere else in my Rails app?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I'm starting to feel crazy because what I want to do is so simple: write a line of javascript in my Rails application.js file that will cause a script somewhere else in the app to execute. I've tried it with jQuery.get() and jQuery.getScript() but nothing seems to work.

Here's some sample code from my application.js file:

```
#application.js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".button").click.function(){
    $.get($(this).attr("href"), null, null, "script");
  });
});
```

or

```
#application.js, excerpt
  $.getScript("index.js.erb", function(){
    alert('script has run');
  });
```

among other variations. I've tried putting the index.js.erb file in the same views folder as my current page, or in the javascripts folder, and even tried making it a pure .js file. The script itself can't be the problem, I'm trying it with lines as simple as:

```
#app/views/index.js.erb)
$('.header').text('new text')
```

Nothing's working for me, please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have an extra quote before "href".

Also, you might try adding the .js extension after href:
...attr("href") + '.js', ...

Comment: Thanks, the extra quote wasn't the problem. And I know that railscast by heart at this point -that's part of why this is so frustrating to me.

Comment: Maybe try changing the javascript/ajax call from "index.js.erb" to "index.js", but leave your file on the server as "index.js.erb"

Comment: Also remember to have a "format.js" line in your index action

Comment: Wow, okay, thanks. The problem was in the format.js line - the page was actually being rendered from another controller, but I changed the controller to specify where the javascript file was and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I would check to get started:

- Any errors in firebug?
- Check the source of your page, does it include jQuery?
- What if you just write an alert in `application.js`, does that work?
- Are you sure you have the code you posted within a `$(document).ready(...)` callback?

Comment: There's a ton of other working jQuery in the application, and when I write an alert, or the line of code I want to execute, in the application.js file it works fine. And everything in the application.js file is wrapped in a $(document.ready(...) callback.

Comment: Ok, so try running the same code in Firebug and see if it throws any errors that way.

Comment: Also, do you see the request to the javascript file in your logs? Does the request ever get sent at all (again, with firebug)?

Comment: Strange I get this error: 304 Not Modified 217ms that links to a line in my jquery.js file

Answer (score 0):

Needs to be put in a:

```
$(function(){
 // your code goes here
});
```

block

Answer (score 0):

Your web server will serve any `*.js` files located in the `public/` directory. It will not serve any static files that are not in `public/` and it will not serve any `*.erb` files even if they are in `public/`. Moreover, `public/` directory is for static files only, and the web server won't run any `*.js` located within `public/` through Erubis.

Instead, you want a separate route controller/action and route for your special ERB JavaScript file, and the ERB JavaScript file should be in the `app/views/`.

Comment: Thanks, I did try it with my index.js.erb file in the same views folder as my index.html.erb file. What do you mean about a 'separate route', though?